# Use two Auth-Type PAP and EAP with FreeRadius

Tags: radius, freeradius, daloradius

I've freeradius server which uses MySQL to store the data.

following is my database

```
radcheck table
+-----+----------+--------------------+----+--------------+
| id  | username | attribute          | op | value        |
+-----+----------+--------------------+----+--------------+
| 474 | varun    | Cleartext-Password | := | sunshine3003 |
+-----+----------+--------------------+----+--------------+


radreply table
+----+----------+--------------+----+-------+
| id | username | attribute    | op | value |
+----+----------+--------------+----+-------+
|  1 | varun    | Fall-Through | =  | Yes   |
+----+----------+--------------+----+-------+


radgroupcheck table
+----+-----------+-----------+----+-------+
| id | groupname | attribute | op | value |
+----+-----------+-----------+----+-------+
|  1 | group1    | Auth-Type | := | PAP |
|  2 | eapgroup  | Auth-Type | := | EAP   |
+----+-----------+-----------+----+-------+


radusergroup table
+----------+-----------+----------+
| username | groupname | priority |
+----------+-----------+----------+
| varun    | eapgroup  |        1 |
| varun    | group1    |        2 |
+----------+-----------+----------+
```

We have two different clients which uses two different Authentication types with free radius , One uses `PAP` and sends the Password in `User-Password` attribute.

and another client user `EAP` and sends the password in `EAP-Message` and `Message-Authenticator`

What i want is, when PAP fails to authenticate or when `User-Password` attribute is not present it should use `EAP` as `Auth-Type` and if `EAP` and `Message-Authenticator` are not present in radius attribute it should reply with Access-reject or Authentication failure message.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: ...That's the first time _ever_ I've heard of a RADIUS client using Message-Authenticator this way.

Comment: Well, when you use `Auth-Type` `EAP` it uses two additional attributes instead of plain text `EAP-Message` and `Message-Authenticator`

But the point is, i want to use both of them instead any single from `PAP` and `EAP`